# loadUpdateData in liquibase, select only some columns from csv

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Assume having the following csv:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
```

where a,b,c are column names and 1,2,3 are values.
Is it possible to load only columns a,b?

```
<loadUpdateData tableName="TABLE" 
            file="file.csv"
            primaryKey="a">     
            <column name="a" header="a"/>
            <column name="b" header="b"/>
</loadUpdateData>
```

This will generate an SQL error, because it will try to insert column c.
I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself but looking at the code (for [`LoadDataChange`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/LoadDataChange.java)) there seems to be an option to "skip" a column config:

```
if ("skip".equalsIgnoreCase(columnConfig.getType())) {
    continue;
}
```

So maybe you can add a column config for '`c`' and set its type to "skip":

```
<column name="c" header="c" type="skip" />
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Comment: The `name` attribute on the `<column>` tag doesn't appear to be necessary to get this to work.